# Freemarker - How to prevent Split builtin from breaking prematurely

Tags: string, freemarker, built-in

I'm still fairly new to Freemarker and am currently trying to output a bulleted list using the Split builtin.

My code so far is so:

```
<#list listingname?split(", ") as x>
&bull; ${x} <br />
</#list>
```

My issue arises when a value from the 'listingname' field contains a comma-space (, ) - this causes the the outputed code to break prematurely.

So for example, let's say:

listingname = "john's company", "bill, bob's tackle and bait", "john do - attorney at law"

The above code would render it as so:

• "john's company"
• "bill
• bob's tackle and bait"
• "john do - attorney at law"

The issue here is that the 2nd set of double-quoted text breaks instead of displaying "bill, bob's tackle and bait" on one line.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass that listing to FreeMarker as a Java `List` or array? I mean, it's like you try to parse the list literals of some language here. That's not something you usually do in templates. And `?split` is just for spliting, it's certainly not smart enough for this.

But if you indeed has to do this, parsing in the template, what syntactical rules does this listing string follow? Like, what if a list item value contains a quotation mark? Will it be escaped like `\"`? If the syntax is compatible with FTL's own syntax, you could do `<#list ('[' + listingname + ']')?eval as x>`.